# Where will movers meet?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am building a small video game and I ended up with this challenging problem, for me :/

I have to movers in the game, `a` and `b`, they are in different positions of a line, both move in the same direction but with different velocities. Velocity of a is bigger than velocity of b. I need to calculate pre-hand where do they will meet so I can put special element in the game there.

This is the graphical representation:

[image]

- a: a position
- b: b position
- va: a velocity
- vb: b velocity
- va > vb
- M?: meeting point position (unknown)

Knowing everything else, how can I determine M?

Comment: Look up the distance formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your given information, you can find functions $p_a$ and $p_b$ that tell you the positions of the objects as functions of time:
$$
p_a(t) = v_a t + a \text{ and } p_b(t) = v_b t + b.
$$
Simply set these equal to one another and solve for $t$ to find *when* they are at the same location. You should find:
$$
t = \frac{b-a}{v_a-v_b}.
$$
Then plug this back in to either position function to find *where* they meet. You should find:
$$
M = \frac{b v_a-a v_b}{v_a-v_b}.
$$